# looking for a compressing" function that keeps low values linear(ish)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

I am looking for a $C^\infty$ (or at least $C^n$ with $n > 2$) function.
Such that $f(x, t) \approx x \text{ if } x < t$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x, t) = 1$.

A function that is similar but lacks the linearity requirement and only takes one parameter is:

$f(x) = \frac{2\arctan(x)}{\pi}$.

The point of this is, I need a function that compresses the real line into the interval [0, 1] such that values below $t \in [0,1]$ are mostly unchanged, but values $>t$ quickly saturate to one.

Comment: Which linearity argument does $\arctan$ fail, exactly? I don't get what you mean by linear-ish

Comment: Where is $f$ defined?

Comment: @Ishan Deo, linear in this context means $f(x) \approx x$

Comment: @zhw. f is defined on $[0, \infty]$

Comment: How can that be? $f$ is a function of two variables.

Comment: Let me explain as I have indeed done a poor job of conveying what $t$ is. That parameter should be constant with respect to all $x$ but used to control the area of the curve where $f(x, t) \approx x$

In other words, pick $t$, with $t$ fixed it should be true that $f(x, t) \approx x$ if $x < t$. Is that more clear?

Comment: What's the problem with $\arctan x$ then? For small $x$, $\arctan x \approx x$.

Comment: @IshanDeo arctan(x) is not bounded above by 1 but by pi / 2